# Can't use circuitikz bipoles in \pgfnode

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

Why I get error ``` Package pgf Error: Unknown shape ``R''. ``` (or with any other bipole) but I can use other symbols with no problem? How to use bipoles with `\pgfnode`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Draw transistor.
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
    % This works.
    \pgfnode{nfet}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}

    % Draw resistor.
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
    % This doesn't work. Why?
    \pgfnode{R}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The difference is that `R` is a kind of alias, that would expand differently depending on other options like `american` or `european`. It's not documented because this is an internal interface, and can change between versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the bipole component names are different from the corresponding pgf shape names. [Circuitikz manual](http://mirror.iopb.res.in/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf) (Page 6, footnote) says:

> For using bipoles as nodes, the name of the node is `<component name>shape`

So for resistor, use `resistorshape` instead of `R`. See few other examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Draw transistor.
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
    % This works.
    \pgfnode{nfet}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}

    % Draw resistor.
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfnode{resistorshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfnode{capacitorshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfnode{cuteinductorshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfnode{americaninductorshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfnode{genericshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}

    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-8cm}{-2cm}}
    \pgfnode{emptydiodeshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfnode{emptyvarcapshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfnode{cspstshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfnode{batteryshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{2cm}{0cm}}
    \pgfnode{ammetershape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PS: Same shape can have multiple names, but the shape name is same. So finding the correct name might be little difficult. Especially when its not documented properly (Index of circuitikz manual is the best shot).

Comment: You mean this: `\pgfnode{european resistorshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}`? It doesn't work...

Comment: @simon I think you have to use `\pgfnode{genericshape}{center}{}{}{\pgfusepath{draw}}` to get that shape.

Comment: OK, but what with other shapes with spaces in their name? Lets say: `cute inductor` or `variable american inductor`?

Comment: @simon I think that naming is not applicable in general

Comment: @Simon `americaninductorshape` and `cuteinductorshape` works..

Comment: OK. I get it. But it definitely should be better documented...

Comment: @Simon Yes. Maybe they were not expecting people to use it as nodes directly. Anyway most of the bipoles works if you append `shape`. Just that you have to find the right name as there are multiple names for the same shape.

Comment: Maybe. I want to create my elements like 3 phase contactor do it's nice to use predefined shapes to speed up my work. Thank you very much :)